# php page can't load MySQL's database

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I'm having some problems while trying to connect a .php with mysql.
here's the connection.php code

```
<?php
$db_host =$_POST['localhost'];
$db_user =$_POST['root'];
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "prtcl";
?>
```

and this is the page where I actually use the connection

```
<?
include("connection.php"); 
?>

...

<?php
$db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);
        mysql_select_db($db_name, $db);
            if (!$db)
              {
              die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
              }
mysql_close($db);             
?>

<body>

...
```

that's what I get when I try to load it ( line 29 is this one:

> $db = mysql_connect($db_host,
>   $db_user, $db_password);

)

> Notice: Undefined variable: db_host in
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.2\www\prtcl\index.php on line 29
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: db_user in
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.2\www\prtcl\index.php on line 29
>
> Notice: Undefined variable:
>   db_password in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.2\www\prtcl\index.php on line 29
>
> Warning: mysql_connect()
>   [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] A
>   connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not (trying to
>   connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.2\www\prtcl\index.php on line 29
>
> Warning: mysql_connect()
>   [function.mysql-connect]: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond. in
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.2\www\prtcl\index.php on line 29
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of
>   30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.2\www\prtcl\index.php on line 29

as you can see I'm using EasyPHP and, since this very code used to work before (with a different db, while using manually configured apache/mysql), may be that the reason? Other infos: I made the db using phpmyadmin and I have win7

thank you

Comment: Why on earth are you assigning your db host and user from form input? especially unvetted form input?

Comment: First tip: replace your "include" with a "require" to check if the file actually exists at the current position.

Comment: @ Mark Baker: never had a problem with that before. If that's wrong, what's the right way to do it?

Comment: Furthering on what @Mark wrote... your code is looking at $_POST data to find values for localhost and root.  That means that you would have submitted data which contains values for those two keys.  Perhaps what you mean to do is `$db_host = 'localhost';` and `$db_user = 'root';`.  To see if this is the problem, add a `print_r($_POST);` right before your `$db_host = ` assigment.

Comment: are you sure your short tags are being accepted? 1st try changing <? to <?php may be your short tag is off. after that we can move further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't **ever** take your db credentials from `$_POST` without validation. This is *such* a terrible idea and this is what's causing your errors, as these keys are not being defined in `$_POST`, but *they could be* and the results could be disastrous!

try putting this in `connect.php`

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "prtcl";

$db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_name, $db);
if(!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

then in your other pages use:

```
require_once("path/to/connect.php");

// ... whatever else you do on this page...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would find out why the $db_host variable is not getting defined. That might be a problem with your form input. Check to see that the name of that input field really is 'localhost'. Also, as Mark Baker mentioned above, you really want to do some input cleansing to guard against sql injection attacks. Plus, is there any reason you can't hardcode the db host info into a configuration file?